# Mysql not accessible to outside

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

On ubuntu 12.04 I can't access mysql from outside.  It works if I use localhost.

In my.conf I have

```
bind-address  = 0.0.0.0
```

So..what could the issue be?  I have 3306 port open to all.  How do I debug?

Comment: Change the `bind-address` to be your IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grant user access on all IP addresses

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
ON mydatabasename.*
TO 'myusername'@'%'
IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword'
```

The key is the "%" wildcard which says the user can log in from any IP